# Series expansion at $x=0$ of $\frac{3x}{1+x^2 + x^4}$

Tags: real-analysis

Need fast solution how to show series expansion of function at x=0:

$$f(x)=\frac{3x}{1+x^2+x^4}$$

Please some hints.

Comment: Another hint is: long division.

Comment: The Maple 17 command $$convert(3*x/(x^4+x^2+1), FPS)  $$ produces [an explicit formula](http://rapidshare.com/files/3015389071/FPS.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom by $1-x^2$.

At the bottom you get $1-x^6$. You probably know how to expand $\frac{1}{1-x^6}$. You certainly know how to expand $\frac{1}{1-t}$.